# How to fix "error: control reaches end of non-void function"?

Tags: c

```
int climbStairs(int n ){

    if(n==1){
        return 1;
    }
    if (n>=2){
         return (2+ climbStairs(n-2)+ climbStairs(n-1));
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I fix the compiler error?

Comment: If `n` is less than 1, what will the function return?

Comment: And don't say that can't happen. When `n == 2`, the recursion does `climbStairs(0)` and `climbStairs(1)`.

Comment: And what happens when `n` is `-123`?

Comment: assume `n == 0`  what do you return in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is not as clever as you. You may well know that the function is never called with `n` less than 1, but the compiler doesn't. Personally I think it's called with `n` as `0` for typical inputs.

Therefore it thinks that program control can reach the function closing brace `}` without an explicit return, which formally is *undefined behaviour* if you make use of the function return value which, to repeat, I think you do.

You have this warning the compiler issues to you elevated to an error, so compilation halts.

Some fixes:

1. Block the recursion with the stronger `if (n <= 1){`.
2. Run-time assert before the closing brace `}` using `assert(false)` or similar.
3. Switch off the elevation of that warning to an error, but do deal with the warning nonetheless.

---

Some advice from @JonathanLeffler

Don't switch off -Werror — it is too valuable. Deal with the warning. assert(n >= 0); at the top; if (n <= 1) { return 1; } as well. Assertions fire in debug builds; erroneous parameter value handled reasonably safely and sanely even if assertions are not enabled.

Comment: Afaics, for any `n > 1` the function `climbstairs(0)` will be called at some point.

Comment: @Ctx: I agree with that.

Comment: Don't switch off `-Werror` — it is too valuable.  Deal with the warning.  `assert(n >= 0);` at the top; `if (n <= 1) { return 1; }` as well.  Assertions fire in debug builds; erroneous parameter value handled reasonably safely and sanely even if assertions are not enabled.

Comment: Another way of avoiding `n < 0` problems is to use `unsigned` instead of `int`.

Comment: *Your compiler is not as clever as you.*  I'd say the compiler is **more** clever in this case. It knows your assumption about the input is likely wrong, because in reality the code will eventually get called with inputs outside the expected range.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Although in that case you might suffer from the dreaded wrap-around and a rather hot CPU.

Answer (score 2):

And in addition to other answers here is another good trick.

If you are absolutely certain that you know more than the compiler, and there's nothing to return, then put an `abort();` as the last line of your function. The compiler is smart enough to know that `abort()` will never return because it causes a program crash. That will silence the warning.

Note that the program crash is a good thing. Because as in this case, when the "impossible thing" does indeed happen, you get the crash and it will pop open in your debugger if you are using one.